# Conditions for col $\mathbf{A} = \mathbb{R}^m$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Say I have an $m \times n$ matrix $\mathbf{A}$. What are the conditions of $\mathbf{A}$ needed for the column space of $\mathbf{A}$ to be equal $\mathbb{R}^m$ - that is, the basis of col $\mathbf{A}$ is also a basis of $\mathbb{R}^m$?. In other words, col $\mathbf{A} = \mathbb{R}^m$.

For example, if you have rank $\mathbf{A} = m$ and $m \leq n$, is col $\mathbf{A} = \mathbb{R}^m$? If so, why?

Answer (score 0):

As the column space of $A$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^m$, if its dimension is equal to $m$, it must be equal. So, is $\operatorname{rank}(A) = m$, then the column space if $\mathbb R^m$, there are no need to assume that $m \leq n$. Also, another (equivalent) condition is that the columns of $A$ forms a linearly independent set of $\mathbb R^m$, that is, $Ax = 0$ implies that $x = 0$.

Comment: Why does rank A = m imply that col A = R^m?

Comment: The rank of $A$ is the dimension of the column space.

Answer (score 0):

Reduce the matrix. m <= n mean 2x3 or 3x3 (square) At most you will have m pivots meaning you will have m linearly independent columns. What is the rank? Gilbert Strang says the rank is the number of pivots after row reduction. We know that the linearly independent columns is the linear combinations of the columns that spans the C(A).